# Firefox crashing like crazy

Tags: 14.04, firefox

Firefox has started crashing like crazy lately. I can't even browse
simple sites without it crashing and it's making Ubuntu unusable right
now, as the reason I switched to Firefox is because Chromium was
crashing a lot, too. I'm really hoping there's someone here, who can help me. It would mean a lot.

Crash Report:

```
Add-ons:
    ubufox%40ubuntu.com:3.2,
    %7B972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a2853208198ce6fd%7D:45.0,
    %7Bd10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b22b9879e08c5d%7D:2.7.2,
    loop%40mozilla.org:1.1.14
AddonsShouldHaveBlockedE10s: 1 
BuildID: 20160304114926 
CrashTime: 1459465487 
EMCheckCompatibility: true 
FramePoisonBase: 7ffffffff0dea000 
FramePoisonSize: 4096 
InstallTime: 1459185263 
Notes:
    OpenGL: Intel Open Source Technology Center -- Mesa DRI Intel(R)
    Haswell Mobile  -- 3.0 Mesa 11.0.2 -- texture_from_pixmap

ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384} 
ProductName: Firefox
ReleaseChannel: release 
SafeMode: 0 
SecondsSinceLastCrash: 283
StartupTime: 1459465212 
TelemetryEnvironment: {
    "build": {
        "applicationId":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}",
        "applicationName":"Firefox",
        "architecture":"x8664",
        "buildId":"20160304114926",
        "version":"45.0",
        "vendor":"Mozilla",
        "platformVersion":"45.0",
        "xpcomAbi":"x86_64-gcc3",
        "hotfixVersion":"20160106.01"
    },
    "partner" {
        "distributionId":"canonical",
        "distributionVersion":"1.0",
        "partnerId":null,
        "distributor":null,
        "distributorChannel":null,
        "partnerNames":[]
    },
    "system": {
        "memoryMB":11913,
        "virtualMaxMB":null,
        "cpu": {
            "count":4,
            "cores":2,
            "vendor":"GenuineIntel",
            "family":6,
            "model":60,
            "stepping":3,
            "l2cacheKB":256,
            "l3cacheKB":3072,
            "speedMHz":3300,
            "extensions": [
                "hasMMX",
                "hasSSE",
                "hasSSE2",
                "hasSSE3",
                "hasSSSE3",
                "hasSSE4_1",
                "hasSSE4_2"
            ]
        },
        "os": {
            "name":"Linux",
            "version":"4.2.0-34-generic",
            "locale":"en-US"
        },
        "hdd": {
            "profile": {
                "model":null,
                "revision":null
            },
            "binary": {
                "model":null,
                "revision":null
            },
            "system": {
                "model":null,
                "revision":null
            }
        },
        "gfx": {
            "D2DEnabled":null,
            "DWriteEnabled":null,
            "adapters": [ {
                "description":"Intel Open Source Technology Center -- Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile",
                "vendorID":"Intel Open Source Technology Center",
                "deviceID":"Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile",
                "subsysID":null,
                "RAM":null,
                "driver":null,
                "driverVersion":"3.0 Mesa 11.0.2",
                "driverDate":null,
                "GPUActive":true
            } ],
            "monitors":[],
            "features": {
                "compositor":"basic"
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "blocklistEnabled":true,
        "e10sEnabled":false,
        "telemetryEnabled":false,
        "isInOptoutSample":false,
        "locale":"en-US",
        "update": {
            "channel":"release",
            "enabled":true,
            "autoDownload":true
        },
        "userPrefs" {
            "browser.cache.disk.capacity":358400,
            "browser.newtabpage.enhanced":true
        },
        "addonCompatibilityCheckEnabled":true,
        "isDefaultBrowser":false,
        "defaultSearchEngine":"google",
        "defaultSearchEngineData": {
            "name":"Google",
            "loadPath":"[distribution]/searchplugins/locale/en-US/google.xml",
            "submissionURL":"https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8"
        }
    },
    "profile": {
        "creationDate":16888
    },
    "addons": {
    "activeAddons": {
        "ubufox@ubuntu.com": {
            "blocklisted":false,
            "description":"Ubuntu modifications for Firefox",
            "name":"Ubuntu Modifications",
            "userDisabled":false,
            "appDisabled":false,
            "version":"3.2",
            "scope":8,
            "type":"extension",
            "foreignInstall":false,
            "hasBinaryComponents":false,
            "installDay":16696,
            "updateDay":16696,
            "signedState":2
        },
        "{d10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d}": {
            "blocklisted":false,
            "description":"Ads were yesterday!",
            "name":"Adblock Plus",
            "userDisabled":false,
            "appDisabled":false,
            "version":"2.7.2",
            "scope":1,
            "type":"extension",
            "foreignInstall":false,
            "hasBinaryComponents":false,
            "installDay":16890,
            "updateDay":16890,
            "signedState":2
        },
        "loop@mozilla.org": {
            "blocklisted":false,
            "description":"Web sharing for Firefox",
            "name":"Firefox Hello Beta",
            "userDisabled":false,
            "appDisabled":false,
            "version":"1.1.14",
            "scope":1,
            "type":"extension",
            "foreignInstall":false,
            "hasBinaryComponents":false,
            "installDay":16891,
            "updateDay":16891,
            "signedState":3
        }
    },
    "theme": {
        "id":"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}",
        "blocklisted":false,
        "description":"The default theme.",
        "name":"Default",
        "userDisabled":false,
        "appDisabled":false,
        "version":"45.0",
        "scope":4,
        "foreignInstall":false,
        "hasBinaryComponents":false,
        "installDay":16864,
        "updateDay":16864
    },
    "activePlugins": [ {
        "name":"Shockwave Flash",
        "version":"11.2.202.577",
        "description":"Shockwave Flash 11.2r202",
        "blocklisted":false,
        "disabled":false,
        "clicktoplay":false,
        "mimeTypes": [
            "application/x-shockwave-flash",
            "application/futuresplash"
        ],
        "updateDay":16888
    } ],
    "activeGMPlugins": {
        "gmp-gmpopenh264": {
            "version":"1.5.3",
            "userDisabled":false,
            "applyBackgroundUpdates":1
        }
    },
    "activeExperiment":{},
    "persona":null
}
Theme: classic/1.0 Throttleable: 1 URL:
http://www.facebook.com
Vendor: Mozilla Version: 45.0 useragent_locale: en-US

This report also contains technical information about the state of the application when it crashed.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry everyone, it seems as if I fixed all the crashing by simply disabling hardware acceleration. I should probably have tried this the first thing I did.

Again, I'm sorry for taking up your time.

Answer (score 0):

This could be way off, but this error report seems to be indicating that it is not necessarily Firefox that is the problem (since you also mentioned chromium having issues).  I'm looking at the top of the report:

`OpenGL: Intel Open Source Technology Center -- Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile -- 3.0 Mesa 11.0.2 -- texture_from_pixmap`.

This may not be the correct direction to point you in, but it seems your OpenGL drivers are not functioning correctly or at the very least aren't playing well with others.  Did you happen to install a different driver recently?  Do you remember if there were any key system updates around the time when chromium started performing very poorly?

You appear to be using the Mesa drivers, and likely have an Intel HD **** integrated graphics cpu?  The Mesa drivers should be exactly what you want...

If you do not have a dedicated graphics card (e.g. an NVIDIA card), I would suggest searching around for `Graphics driver <your specific cpu>`, maybe including Ubuntu in the search as well.  `lscpu` should give you the exact model name.  It could be that your specific CPU needs some special setup?  This is *very* unlikely.

Again, I don't know that new / different graphics drivers are the right solution here.  If you do decide to make a stab at this, definitely make a *full* backup of your system so it is easy to revert to.  Messing up the graphics drivers can have a lot of really annoying side effects (including not being able to load Unity [the desktop window system]).

The only other thing that comes to mind is you could try avoiding `ubufox` and see if you have different results.  After you uninstall firefox, you can follow the directions here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/661384/418575

This may give you different results?  But that also shouldn't really be necessary.

Comment: There are no special drivers for Intel cards, so whatever Ubuntu has is what it has. `nouveau` is the open-source driver for NVIDIA.

Comment: you are correct, `nouveau` is a bad suggestion. however there are intel specific drivers: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads

i one time had to install an older version of mesa because the distribution version caused me problems